# Find the limit of $(3+\frac{12}{n})^{\frac{5}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3+\frac{12}{n}\right)^{\frac{5}{n}}$$
I know the answer is $1$ but I don't know why. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you!

Comment: Sure there is no typo? Typically the $n$ in the fraction and in the exponent should cancel out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for any number $n$ ,$\frac{n}{\infty}=0$ so directly plugging in infinity as n we get $(3+0)^0=1$

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to use that in this problem.

Comment: If limit isnt undefined like $0/0$ then we can directly plug the value

Answer (score 0):

This one looks more confusing than it is!

As $n \to \infty$,

$$ 3 + \dfrac{12}{n} \quad \to \quad 3 $$

and similarly, in the exponent, $5/n \to 0$. That means as $n \to \infty$, the expression becomes

$$ 3^0 = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=\left(3+\frac{12}{n}\right)^{\frac{5}{n}}$. Then

$$\ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln \left(3+\frac{12}{n}\right)^{\frac{5}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{5}{n}\left(3+\frac{12}{n}\right)=0$$

So $L=e^{\ln L}=e^0=1$.

Comment: Can you explain more about why this equation holds? I'm confused about both deduction.

Comment: @Kelan which part do you find confusing? I simply used that $f(x)=\ln x$ is continous so we can exchange the limit, and the fact that $\ln L=a$ if and only if $L=e^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$A_n=(3+\frac{12}{n})^{\frac{5}{n}}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A_n)=\frac 1n \log\Big(3+\frac{12}{n}\Big)$$ When $n\to \infty$, $\log\Big(3+\frac{12}{n}\Big)\to \log(3)$ which makes $\log(A_n)\simeq\frac 1n \log(3)\to 0$ and so $A_n\to 1$

You could also have use Taylor series $$\log\Big(3+\frac{12}{n}\Big)=\log(3)+\log\Big(1+\frac{4}{n}\Big)=\log (3)+\frac{4}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ making $$\log(A_n)=\frac{\log (3)}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$